# Format a column of data in excel into percentage using win32 python

Tags: python, excel, winapi, format, pywin32

Trying to convert a column of data into percentage using win32 python in excel

```
xlSheet.Range("C3:C7").Style = "Percentage"
```

This does not work. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it.

The correct formatting name is `"Percent"`.

So try:

```
xlSheet.Range("C3:C7").Style = "Percent"
```

Comment: Thanks! I was close but wouldn't have gotten it!

Comment: With percent it converts lets say 0.170691 to 17% is there any way to make that 17.07%

Comment: `xlSheet.Range("C3:C7").NumberFormat = "0.00%"` would do what you need.